# How to avoid duplication of url call to video-stream in Samsung Tizen?

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

My Smart-TV client on Samsung Tizen always calls a video-stream url twice.
I just pass the url for hls-stream, like it's shown in the documentation [here](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/guides/multimedia/media-playback/using-avplay.html)

```
webapis.avplay.open('yourMediaURI');
```

In Charles I see the url always calls twice.

Does exist the way to avoid double url call on Samsung Tizen? Another Smart-TV clients, like LG one, don't have this problem.

Comment: Are both api calls the same? is it possible that the first one is an OPTIONS call? How much time elapses between the calls? What type of resource is it that you are requesting?